# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to MongoDB using Anaconda3 (64-bit). The code I am using:

```
import signal
import subprocess



proc = subprocess.Popen(['mongod'] preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

But I am getting below error

> ```
> AttributeError                            
> Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-45-f94c14f3a553> in <module>()
>       2 import subprocess
>       3 #proc = subprocess.Popen('mongod', close_fds=True)
> ----> 4 proc =subprocess.Popen(['mongod'], shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
>
> AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'
> ```

Comment: Are you on Unix? `os.setsid` is only available on Unix.

Comment: No I am in Windows

Comment: Then read the docs- `os.setsid` is not available on Windows, it is only available on Unix. As a general rule, if you want to do anything with the `os` module, check the docs since some/lots of functionality is OS dependent (as suggested by the name) [here's a link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, you cannot use `os.setsid`, `preexec_fn` parameter `subprocess.Popen` also unavailable.

You can create a subprocess with a new process group with creationflags` parameter [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['mongod'],
    shell=True,
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
)
```